# List all tables containing a given column name

Tags: mysql, information-schema

How do a I list all tables containing a given column name? I'm using Mysql version 
4.1.13-nt-log. I know versions less than 5 dont have an information_scheme DB.

Comment: a counter-question: why do you need that? :)

Comment: If you seriously want to do it you can output results for SHOW TABLES and SHOW COLUMNS FROM into a text file in command line then use Perl and grep for search

Answer (score 31):

Find all tables and columns where column names are like the search term:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%partial_column_name%'
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';
```

Comment: The OP was quite specific about NOT using information_schema, this does not answer the question.

Comment: + 1 because it was what I was looking for when searching.

Comment: +1 for the same reason -- solved my particular problem and saved me oodles of time.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mysqldump -u root -p –all-databases –single-transaction > all.sql
```

and then do the searching the old-school way in a text editor with find

---

also found this... looks promising, but I'm not sure how ambitious you are

http://mike.kruckenberg.com/presentations/Creating_INFORMATION_SCHEMA.pdf

Comment: A nice simple solution, but I would suggest using the no-data option, since all you care about is the schema...

Answer (score 0):

Much more easily

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM your_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 'your_column_name';
```

Answer (score -4):

```
select table_name,column_name,data_type,data_length 
from user_tab_columns 
where column_name LIKE 'WHATEVER_U_WANT'
;
```